# asp.net session time out same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, session

I am using asp.net and I am very new to it. I was given a task by my manager to debugs an asp.net system. One of the problem of this system is that when users try to write details in a text box for a long time, the session will time out and eventually all the words that users haven't finish typing will gone. So when user login, they have to type all the words again.

So I would like to ask is there any way to like, temporary save the texts before session time out? Then, when user login after the session time out, the system will direct back to the page where the user did not manage finish writing. Thanks and sorry for the bad english...

Answer (score 0):

change setting your web.config page

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="480" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout in web.config, can also use timespan--20 minutes is default, also The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and state-server modes.

```
<sessionState 
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="number of minutes"............

   ....../>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can follow this approach for what you need to save user from
>   typing again same information after re login
>
> 1. Use a timer to save your page controls value to Data table

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval=600000;//10 min timer
    aTimer.Enabled=true;
}


DataTable table = new DataTable();
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
        // code to save data in datatable;
       //like
    table.Clear();//Refresh the table
    table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));//No need to create column again and again.As i am doing here :|
    table.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text);//This is just sample code
     }
```

> After these lines of code in every 10 min your data will be saved in datatable. You can also use the same datatable to save the data in Database.
>
> 2. After time out your page will be redirected to login or some other page. Now the tricky part is when you re login in the page load event just check that is data table consist any row or not
>      if yes then you have to just fetch the data from data table and fill your control again with the data.if no it means it is fresh login and dont have to do anything!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(table!=null)
                if(table .Rows.Count>0)
                {
                   Textbox1.Text=table.Row[0][0].ToString();//In this way you can fill controls again
//And user need not to type data again!! 


   }
                 }
```

> So in this way you can preserve the data entered by the user even after the timeout.

For understanding the Data Table you can follow this link [Data table](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable)